# How to compile scss file that uses compass in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: npm, sass, compass-sass, npm-install, laravel-5.3

This is `gulpfile.js` of Laravel 5.3,

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js');
});
```

It could compile scss and js file,but,if the scss file uses compass,how to compile it?

I tried "laravel-elixir-sass-compass": "^0.5.0",but it can not be installed successfully.

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0-nightly2016080329e49fc286
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5

npm ERR! cb is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0-nightly2016080329e49fc286
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5

npm ERR! cb is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\wnmp\www\laravel-5-3-demo\npm-debug.log
```

What should I do?